# node.js - Empty File after executing the wrong command

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, gulp, browserify

Every time i execute the following command, i get an empty main.js file

```
browserify -o main.js bundle.js
Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/test/src/js/bundle.js' from '/var/www/test/src/js'
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:55:21
at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:69:43)
at onex (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:92:31)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:22:47
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:112:15)
```

I know, this command is wrong, but why is my main.js 0 Bytes large after the execution? The problem occurs not only with browserify, also with gulp. If an error occurs, the file is empty...that is strange. I don't want to loose all my code only by typing the wrong command. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#usage) it says that the option `-o` you use specifies the file to write output to, and by running;

```
browserify -o main.js bundle.js
```

you're saying `write to 'main.js' file`. Since build fails, there is no ouput, so nothing is written into `main.js`, but the content there is probably deleted.

Try like this:

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know that the option has to be placed AFTER main.js but it was not so clear why i loose all the code by a simple typo. Probably i'm not the first person who runs into that error :-)

Comment: you're welcome, you can accept my answer if it helped